# expectation value of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

In the statistics lecture that I'm attending, the professor once used the following: $X, Y$ random variables and i.i.d., then $$\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$$
I was trying to see an argument why this should be the case, but I could not find one. Why exactly am I allowed to do this?

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: $E[XY]=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}xyf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdx=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}xyf_X(x)f_Y(y)dxdy=...$ Independence does matter. The identity of the distributions does not matter. Also, it matters that the expectations exist.

Comment: I've thought of that, but why is $f_{XY}$ two-dimensional? Isn't it more like $X\cdot Y : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ - so a one-dimensional random-variable?

Comment: $f_{XY}$ is a notation for the PDF of random variable $XY$ and is one-dimensional. $f_{X,Y}$ is a notation for the PDF of random vector $(X,Y)$ and is two-dimensional.

Comment: You mean $X\cdot Y$? The product of the two random variable. In order to calculate the expectation of a function of two random variables (like $X+Y$ or $X\cdot Y$ or $\ln(X^2)-\cos(\frac{X}{Y})$) we need their common distribution. In general we need to know (if the common density exits) $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I think I see the idea.